# What are the opening dates for ski areas at Nagano?

Tags: japan, seasonal, skiing

Are there fixed dates for the openings of ski resorts at Nagano or does that depend on the snow fall?

Comment: I can't help with this question, but you mean "Nagano", right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Snow Japan](http://www.snowjapan.com/e/general/winter-sports-in-japan-the-season.html),

> For most resorts, the ski and snowboard season in Japan generally
>   starts around mid-December and goes through until around early April.
>   Opening of course depends on the level of snow that accumulates at a
>   particular resort, and some resorts do actually open as early as late
>   October ("early skiing") and can continue to operate until mid-May
>   (for "spring skiing"), usually with the help of snowmaking machines.

They [list](http://www.snowjapan.com/e/resorts/prefecturedata.php?prefecture=Nagano) 88 resorts in Nagano so you could use that as a starting point to find resort web sites for more details and predictions about this year. I know that Canadian resorts will have a planned opening date on their website before they are actually open.